# Should external drives be converted to ext3?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs, ext3

I switched over from Windows to Linux. I have an external drive that has basically just media files on it. Are there any advantages to converting this to ext3, or should I just leave it as ntfs3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

imho, leave it as ntfs. the support for ntfs across different OS is much better than for ext3, so you can use the drive when a buddy shows up and wants to impress you with his mac or his windows.

Comment: Agreed. If it ain't broke…

Answer (score 1):

For external drives that will **only** ever be used with Linux, I always reformat them with ext3 so that extended attributes will be preserved.  However, if the external drive will be used with multiple OSes then I use ntfs.  Linux support for NTFS is very mature.